# Need some clarification for $\frac{d}{dt} [\det A(t)]=\det A(t) \cdot \operatorname*{tr}[A^{-1}(t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt} A(t)]$.

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I was reading [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/214924/137215) that explains why $$\frac{d}{dt} [\det A(t)]=\det A(t) \cdot \operatorname*{tr}[A^{-1}(t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt} A(t)]$$ However I don't understand exactly the following step :

$$\det A (t) \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{\det \bigl(A (t)^{-1} A (t + h)\bigr) - 1}{h}=\det A (t) \operatorname{tr} \Bigl(A (t)^{-1}\frac{d A}{dt} (t) \Bigr)$$

Comment: Remark: another proof just uses the multivariate chain rule and the fact cofactors are partial derivatives of the determinant. Then the given formula just follows from Cramer's rule.

Comment: Thank you @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, do you happen to have a reference?

Comment: You don't need a reference. My comment contained the whole proof in condensed form but you need some effort. First see a determinant as a function of $n^2$ variables. How would you use Laplace expansion to find the partial derivative with respect to the entry $a_{i,j}$?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post you mentioned takes for granted that the derivative of the determinant at the identity equals trace.  That is,
\begin{equation*}
\det(\text{Id} + A) = 1 + \text{tr}(A) + o(\|A\|) \quad \text{as} \, \, \|A\| \to 0.
\end{equation*}

From this, we see that
\begin{align*}
\det(A(t)^{-1}A(t +h)) &= \det(\text{Id} + (A(t)^{-1}A(t+h) - \text{Id})) \\
&= 1 + \text{tr}(A(t)^{-1}A(t +h) - \text{Id}) + o(\|A(t)^{-1}A(t+h) - \text{Id}\|)
\end{align*}
Now observe that $A(t+h) = A(t) + h \frac{d}{dt}A(t) + o(h)$ as $h \to 0$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
\text{tr}(A(t)^{-1}A(t+h) - \text{Id}) = h \text{tr}\left(A(t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt}A(t)\right) + o(h)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
o(\|A(t)^{-1}A(t+h) - \text{Id}\|) = o(h).
\end{equation*}
Putting it all together, we deduce that
\begin{equation*}
\text{det}(A(t)^{-1}A(t+h)) = 1 + h \text{tr} \left(A(t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt}A(t) \right) + o(h),
\end{equation*}
or, equivalently,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\text{det}(A(t)^{-1}A(t+h)) - 1}{h} = \text{tr} \left(A(t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt}A(t) \right).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you @Peter Morfe. I actually thought it was a one-line argument.